# Access VBA: Invalid field data type

Tags: ms-access, vba

With an Access VBA, I am trying to load a file from a directory to the table `[table name]` in the field `[field name]` which `Data Type` is `Attachment`.

The problem is that I get the error `Invalid field data type`.

[image]

The code is the following.

```
Dim SQL As String
SQL = " SELECT * FROM [table name] WHERE ID = '10'"

Dim VESRecordSet As Recordset
Set VESRecordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)

VESRecordSet![field name].LoadFromFile "D:\Documents\file.vsd"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made multiple errors:

1. To work with attachments, you should use the `DAO.RecordSet2` object
2. You need to open the child recordset containing the file data before you can use `.LoadFromFile`
3. You should use `.Edit` and `.Update` when editing and updating a recordset

Final code:

```vb
Dim SQL As String
SQL = " SELECT * FROM [table name] WHERE ID = '10'"

Dim VESRecordSet As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsAttachments As DAO.Recordset2
Set VESRecordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)

VESRecordSet.Edit
Set rsAttachments = VESRecordSet![field name].Value
rsAttachments.AddNew
rsAttachments.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile "D:\Documents\file.vsd"
rsAttachments.Update
rsAttachments.Close
VESRecordSet.Update
VESRecordSet.Close
```